# WooCommerce Product - some products are only visible in google, can't see them on shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Some of product posts on my friends shop page based on WooCommerce are only visible as search results in google - they somehow are not present neither on shop page, nor could be searched for using search form.

Using flatsome child theme, haven't noticed any strange differences in product posts in wp-admin, any idea what's wrong?

**Product not displaying in search form nor shop page:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Product displaying OK:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas what might be causing one of those not display on shop's page itself, but being present in google results (products page exists, it somehow is not seen by loop)?

Comment: Are you using a caching service such as cloudflare ? One explanation might be that you’re seeing a cached version of a webpage that was created some time ago

Comment: @florian Actually the only one is W3 Total Cache - i have tried purging all cache and disabling the plugin tho, checked in incognito and still same thing. The product that's not displaying seems not to have postmeta `_visibility` but this shouldn't be an issue, should it?

Comment: Could you send the link to a product page ? In addition, do you have the toolbar enabled ? It would be helpful to get direct access to the page, “Edit product” and get direct access to the product page’s backend : https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Screens#Toolbar